# finding location in codename1

Tags: java-me, location, codenameone

I'm following [this](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Determining_Current_Location_via_Cell_ID) tutorial for finding locations on my j2me device. In the default codename1 mechanism, it tries to find it out through GPS. But my phone doesn't have it. So it opens the bluetooth connect screen. I'm using the following code.

```
com.codename1.location.LocationManager.getLocationManager().getCurrentLocationSync();
```

In the tutorial mentioned, we could change the retrieval mechanism to CELL-ID or Network, by doing the following.

```
 //Specify the retrieval method to Online/Cell-ID
 int[] methods = {(Location.MTA_ASSISTED | Location.MTE_CELLID | Location.MTE_SHORTRANGE | Location.MTY_NETWORKBASED)};

 // Retrieve the location provider
 provider = LocationUtil.getLocationProvider(methods, null);
```

Is there any way we could do a similar stuff in codename1 ??

Comment: @Shai Almog: any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0):

We don't support other methods in J2ME devices at this point in time. You can use [native interfaces](http://www.codenameone.com/3/post/2014/01/native-interface.html) to implement it.

Comment: hi, thanx for the rply. I followed though native interfaces and implemented it. However, Location api is jsr179. When I am trying to send the j2me build the codename1 build server is generating the following error:

import com.nokia.mid.location.LocationUtil;
                             ^
/tmp/build1833262896930608218xxx/tmpsrc/userclasses/Network/NativeCoordinatesImpl.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
   provider = LocationUtil.getLocationProvider(methods, null);
              ^
  symbol:   variable LocationUtil
  location: class NativeCoordinatesImpl

Comment: LocationUtil is not a part of JSR 179. Its a Nokia class.

Comment: please help me over here, why it is not able to compile . after all its a nokia class!! what is the way out of it. I want to get the location. any help would be very great.

Comment: You need to use JSR 179 API's not Nokia API's since those won't work on a device that isn't from Nokia.

Comment: Our main target is nokia devices only. Also nokia provides a reliable mechanism through LocationUtil class to find the location(without using GPS but using cell IDS). A workaround which I thought is to attach a jar file(which is compiled using nokia sdk) with the codename1 project. Is this possible?

Comment: If you target only Nokia I suggest using the Nokia SDK. Using a jar would probably fail during the obfuscation stage.
You can use JSR 179 which does provide cell ID location options.